# Coding secondary displays

Tags: android

In my nexus tablet, I can see in Settings - Developers options, we have an option to "Simulate Secondary Displays". For one of my prototyping, I want to create a secondary display of my custom resolution. Can someone please point out, how can I create (code) a secondary display same as available in "Developer Options" but with my custom resolution?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html ?  It seems to imply the display size is determined by the device connected

Comment: Yes  read that. In my case, I want to create my virtual display on native side and attach it to the presentation object.

Answer (score 0):

There's no public interface you can code against to create simulated secondary display. You'll have to hack the platform and build your own Android dist if you need to do that.